# how to connect to yahoo messenger through yahoo iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to develop an application in iPhone which will connect to various Instant Messenger and currently working to connect to yahoo messenger.
Can anyone help me to find any api or source which will be helpful for me.
Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

[ycoderscookbook](http://www.ycoderscookbook.com/) is the best resource to learn all about Yahoo IM integration. have a look at it..